# Understanding the results of this printf

Tags: c++, string, escaping, printf

I try to use a "carriage return" ASCII value in a char array and then use printf("%s") to print the string, but I get strange results.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char text[10];
    text[0] = '1';
    text[1] = '2';
    text[2] = 13;
    text[3] = 'n';
    text[4] = '3';
    text[5] = 13 ;
    text[6] = '4';

    printf("%s", text);
}
```

and the output is: `43`

but when I add one character to the array like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char text[10];
    text[0] = '1';
    text[1] = '2';
    text[2] = 13;
    text[3] = 'n';
    text[4] = '3';
    text[5] = 13;
    text[6] = '4';
    text[7] = '5';

    printf("%s", text);
}
```

the output is `45`

Then I use the character `10` instead of `13` like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char text[10];
    text[0] = '1';
    text[1] = '2';
    text[2] = 10 ;
    text[3] = 'n';
    text[4] = '3';
    text[5] = 10 ;
    text[6] = '4';
    text[7] = '5';

    printf("%s", text);
}
```

the output becomes:

```
12
n3
45
```

Can somebody explain to me the reason for the difference between the first output and the second output?

What is different between the character `10` and the character `13` in the way function `printf("%s")` deals with them?

Comment: Carriage return puts the cursor at the beginning of the current line, but doesn't move down one line. So the subsequent characters overwrite previous ones. ASCII code `10` is line feed character, also known as `\n` - it moves down to the next line.

Comment: Your character array is not null-terminated, thus `"%s"` is not guaranteed to print just 8 characters.  The `printf` will keep outputting characters until it finds the null.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is undefined behaviour; the behaviour you describe is not guaranteed

Comment: Note that you also (better?) could use `'\r'` and `'\n'` as character literals instead of their ASCII values (13 and 10). And yes - printf prints till nul termination, so you have to add a `text[8] = '\0';` too (or just 0). Also, use `<iostream>` not `"iostream"` (I even fixed that while editting your question, couldn't help myself). Also, note that `printf` is the C-style way to write output. You shouldn't be using it in C++, nor does `<iostream>` declare it. Whatever book or tutorial you are using to learn C++, it is bad. Stop using it.

Comment: I also removed the `using namespace std;` as it is bad practice and neither relevant here, nor used (printf being C code isn't in namespace std).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/):

1. *10* stands for `'\n'`
2. *13* stands for `'\r'`

**\n (newline)**:

Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line.

**\r (carriage return)**:

Moves the active position to the initial position of the current line.

*Before proceeding, make sure that your string is null terminated. Add `\0` to mark the end of the string and avoid undefined behaviour.*

### Case 1

Printing `text` = "12\rn3\r34"

1. print 1 *{1}*
2. print 2 *{12}*
3. `\r` cursor goes back (to 1) *{12}*
4. print n (overwriting 1) *{n2}*
5. print 3 (overwriting 2) *{n3}*
6. `\r` cursor goes back (to n) *{n3}*
7. print 4 (overwriting n) *{43}*

*Thus, the output is **43***.

### Case 2

Printing `text` = "12\rn3\r345"

Same as the previous steps 1-7 *{43}*

8. print 5 (overwriting 3) *{45}*

*Thus, the output is **45***.

### Case 3

Printing `text` = "12\nn3\n45"

1. print 1
2. print 2
3. `\n` cursor goes to the next line
4. print n
5. print 3
6. `\n` cursor goes to the next line
7. print 4
8. print 5

*Thus, the output is*

***12***

***n3***

***45***

Comment: The result could be that, plus any further junk, since the character array that the OP had was not null-terminated.  You should mention that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Done.